# What is standard resolution of android tablet?

Tags: android, android-layout

What is standard resolution for android tablet?or an emulator?

Comment: @Downvoter - plz leave a comment as to why the question has been downvoted.

Comment: The downvote is not from me, but I guess it was downvoted because there is no standard resolution. There are quite a number of tablets out there with different resolutions and in the emulator you can choose your resolution.

Comment: @nonnb i agree with you and why want close this question plz leave comment all downvoter and which had tag for close

Comment: Now or next year? Or 2 years ago?

Comment: Just read the text below about why this was closed.  Clue:  you're erroneously presupposing that there's a standard resolution.  And anyway, suppose there was one; why not just google for the answer yourself?

Comment: @Poldie actually, if you Google for that you arrive at this page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't only develop you application for one resolution. Take a look at this, it's very helpful.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 26):

below are unique resolution for Smartphone and Tablet of Android

```
Sr. Resolution
1   2560*1600
2   1366*768
3   1280*800
4   1280*768
5   1024*768
6   1024*600
7   960*640
8   960*540
9   854*480
10  800*600
11  800*480
12  800*400
13  640*360
14  640*240
15  480*320
16  400*240
17  320*240
```

and I think `1024*600`
`800*480` are standard resolution

[Ref 1](http://www.gravlab.com/2013/11/21/common-android-screen-resolutions-video/)

[Ref 2](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[Ref 3](http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php)

Comment: for 10” tablet 720x1280 ldpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc

ref : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#ConfigurationExamples